# Пропала Россия при создании платежного аккаунта firebase

Tags: firebase

Пропала Россия в списке стран при создание платежного аккаунта Firebase. Пробовал выбрать другую страну, но как я понимаю, не дает добавить русскую карту. КТо то столкнулся еще с этим, есть ли какие то способы обойти ограничения?

Comment: Положительный ответ лежит в области политики (международных отношений)

Comment: Я так понял автор вопроса политикой не интересуется, россию уже несколько месяцев отовсюду выпиливают, уже почти из всех сервисов. За что? Риторический вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Возможность привязать российскую карту к сервисам Google есть у всех, это связанно с ведением санкции против России